# PowerShell AD Module - Variables in Filter

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

Sorry for the simple question to start, but I am stumped on the answer.

My code is simple... I want to take a variable from command line into my script and use that variable as a Filter string within an AD command.  I have as follows:

```
PARAM($myOU)

$FoundOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -SearchBase ="OU=Offices,DC=dc1,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

So, I want to replace *"*"* with *$myOU*... I am at a lost on how to do this.  I have tried things like  *-Filter Name $myOU*, etc, but no luck.  Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I am not sure this is the best option, but this seemed to work (tried it just after posting - should have tried before posting)

    $FoundOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '*$($myOU)*'" -SearchBase ="OU=Offices,DC=dc1,DC=domain,DC=com"

Anyway, this worked...  again, not sure if the best, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Use string interpolation like so:

```
$FoundOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$myOU'" -SearchBase="OU=Offices,DC=dc1,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Note that string interpolation only happens with double quoted strings so swap the order of single & double quotes so the variable will be interpolated.  Also using `$($myOU)` is unnecessary in this case.  You typically use a sub-expression when you need to access a property e.g. `$($myOU.Length)` or in general evaluate an expression inside a string.