# Using "-Filter" with a variable

Tags: powershell, filter

I try to filter out something like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "chalmw-dm*" -and Enabled -eq "true"} ...
```

This works like a charm and gets exactly what I want...

Now I want the "name -like ..." part as a variable like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like '$nameregex' -and Enabled -eq "true"} |
```

I checked several questions (for example, *[PowerShell AD Module - Variables in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782255/powershell-ad-module-variables-in-filter)*), but this isn't working for me.

I tried it with the following:

```
$nameRegex = "chalmw-dm*"
$nameRegex = "`"chalmw-dm*`""
```

And also in the `Get-ADComputer` command with those `'` and without.

Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: variables are not interpolated in single quote strings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need quotes around the variable, so simply change this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like '$nameregex' -and Enabled -eq "true"}
```

into this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like $nameregex -and Enabled -eq "true"}
```

Note, however, that the scriptblock notation for filter statements is misleading, because the statement is actually a string, so it's better to write it as such:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like '$nameregex' -and Enabled -eq 'true'"
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/1630171). [Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029622/1630171).

And FTR: you're using wildcard matching here (operator `-like`), not regular expressions (operator `-match`).

Answer (score 1):

Add double quote

```
$nameRegex = "chalmw-dm*"
```

`-like "$nameregex"` or `-like "'$nameregex'"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$NameRegex = "chalmw-dm"  
$NameR = "$($NameRegex)*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like $NameR -and Enabled -eq $True}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or

```
-like '*'+$nameregex+'*'
```

if you would like to use wildcards.