# How to pass a variable to -Filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

I have come across a very strange situation in PS.

In a script I have, there is a cmdlet (`Get-Mailbox`) which pulls back a few mailboxes and stores them in `$mailboxes`.

I then loop through this as follows to find a matching AD account.

```
foreach ($user in $mailboxes) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $user.UserPrincipalName}
}
```

When I run this it errors saying that it can't find the property `UserPrincipalName` on `$user`.

I have debugged the script and tested it thoroughly. At the point where it errors if I type `$user.UserPrincipalName` it outputs a list of UPNs and their date type is string so the property is there and has data.

I  came to the conclusion that for some reason `-Filter` can't see the `$user` variable - as if it is isolated inside the {} brackets which I have heard can be the case with functions. However if I modify the code like so it works.

```
foreach ($user in $mailboxes) {
    $name = $user.UserPrincipalName
    Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $name}
}
```

Although this fixes my problem I'd like to learn why the first example doesn't work. Can anyone explain?

Something worth noting is the get-mailbox actually connects to Exchange Online  first and returns a data type of:

```
Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox
```

but when the `Get-ADUser` command errors it says the the object is  of type `PSCustomobject`. I think this maybe part of the problem.

Comment: So... I can't see how to edit this post but I noticed a typo right at the top. The $userlist should say $mailboxes or that would cause a major issue of course!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "userprincipalname -eq '$($user.userprincipalname)'"
```

I don't know why, but there's some more discussion here about which syntaxes do and don't work with Get-ADUser, and how the scriptblock syntax you are using works with a full user object but not with a PSCustomObject, here:

http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2015-11-17-ad-filter

Comment: I know about that, I just didn't put it down in my post as I'm not looking for alternatives but trying to out my it fails. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Take a look a the link in the answer. [Also related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34029622/1630171).