# Export Issue with foreach and Get-ADUser -Filter

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I think I'm having an issue with foreach loop handling. But I don't understand it why does not working. So  I am getting unexpetected result. I've tried several variations but no luck.

```
$reportdate = Get-Date -Format ssddmmyyyy
$csvreportfile = "c:\export\ALLADUsers_$reportdate.csv"

Import-Csv -Path "c:\export\list.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter "EmployeeId -eq $($user.EmployeeID)" |
        Select-Object @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
            @{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
            @{Label = "Display Name";Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},
            @{Label = "Logon Name";Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}},
            @{Label = "WhenCreated";Expression = {$_.whenCreated}},
            @{Label = "Full address";Expression = {$_.StreetAddress}},
            @{Label = "City";Expression = {$_.City}},
            @{Label = "State";Expression = {$_.st}},
            @{Label = "Post Code";Expression = {$_.PostalCode}},
            @{Label = "Country/Region";Expression = {if (($_.Country -eq 'GB')) {'United Kingdom'} else {''}}},
            @{Label = "Job Title";Expression = {$_.Title}},
            @{Label = "Company";Expression = {$_.Company}},
            @{Label = "Description";Expression = {$_.Description}},
            @{Label = "Department";Expression = {$_.Department}},
            @{Label = "Office";Expression = {$_.OfficeName}},
            @{Label = "Phone";Expression = {$_.telephoneNumber}},
            @{Label = "Email";Expression = {$_.Mail}},
            @{Label = "Manager";Expression = {%{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Server $ADServer -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName}}},
            @{Label = "Account Status";Expression = {if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')) {'Enabled'} else {'Disabled'}}, # the 'if statement# replaces $_.Enabled
            @{Label = "Last LogOn Date";Expression = {$_.lastlogondate}}
} | Export-Csv -Path $csvreportfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Assume the Input CSV is like:

```
EmployeeID
16507
16534
16587
16622
16631
16632
16659
16661
16663
16666
16688
16713
16728
16753
16830
```

Output CSV :

```
"First Name","Last Name","Display Name","Logon Name","WhenCreated","Full address","City","State","Post Code","Couny/Region","Job Title","Company","Description","Department","Office","Phone","Email","Manager","Account Status","Last LogOn Date"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso.","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
"Jax","Teller","Jax Teller","JaxT","09.11.2012 12:34:35",,"Foobar","13685",,"","Consultant","Contoso","Contoso/
 - ","Research","","1111111111 (1111)","Jax.Teller@Contoso.com.",,"Enabled","16.08.2016 15:50:27"
```

Comment: Umm... so, what *is* the "unexpected result"? How *exactly* does the code "not work"? Assuming it's the filter expression: please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34028164/1630171).

Comment: I mean as  "unexpected result" its returning an duplicated employeeid user which is non included within  CSV file such as 13685 ID

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "duplicated"? How did you verify that the employee ID is incorrect, since you're not including that information in the output? Generally, please provide more information to allow us to understand the problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer Hope this helps to more understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see. You're using a variable `$user` in your filter, which seems to have been populated somewhere before. That means for each input ID you actually fetch the same user object instead of the object with the given ID. `13685` just appears to be the value of the `st` attribute of that user account.

Replace `$user` with the current object variable `$_` and the problem will disappear.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\export\list.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter "EmployeeId -eq $($_.EmployeeID)" |
        Select-Object ...
} | Export-Csv $csvreportfile -NoType
```

---

As a side note, use calculated properties only if you actually do something with a property (like rename the property, change/re-format the value, etc.). Otherwise simply put the property name in the list. It's utterly pointless to just put the value of a property into a calculated property with the same name:

```
@{Label = "City";Expression = {$_.City}}  # <- useless!
```