# Manage AD Group members using Powershell, CSV & extensionAttribute1

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory-group

I have seen various posts that cover similar topics to this. But none that match my exact requirements.

My aim is:

- Use a CSV containing col 1 (`ADGroupName`), col 2 (`extensionAttirbute1`)
- Delete users from AD groups based on CSV
- Add users to AD groups based on CSV

I'm sure this can be done simply however, to get it to work with the `extensionAttribute1` value, is proving difficult.

Below is some of the code:

So, I have 2 functions.

- First creates CSVs to work from. (Working).
- Second function adds/removes AD groups based on CSV contents. (Working).

Below is where I left the final function after wiping out various bits of code after it didn't work.

```
Function SyncGroups {
  $Groups = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\GroupMembership.csv"

  foreach ($user in $Groups) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Group -Members $user.extensionAttribute1
    Get-ADUser -Filter {extensionAttribute1 -eq $user.extensionAttribute1}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post some of your code?

Comment: What have you tried to make the code from other posts work in your scenario. SO is not a place where we help you with particular problems in your code, not a place where we do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry. I was dashing out. I did not mean to cause offence Ansgar..

Comment: No offense taken. Just pointing out what you can and cannot expect from SO. And of course I meant to write *"SO **is** a place where we help you with particular problems in your code"* (scratch the "not" in that half sentence).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is a common misunderstanding of how the parameter `-Filter` works (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029622/1630171) to a similar question). It's better to think of the argument to the parameter as a string (because that's essentially what it is, despite the notation), and define it as such.

Either assign `$user.extensionAttribute1` to a variable and use that variable in the expression:

```
foreach ($user in $Groups) {
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Group -Members $user.extensionAttribute1
  $attr = $user.extensionAttribute1
  Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute1 -eq '$attr'"
}
```

or put `$user.extensionAttribute1` in a [subexpression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

```
foreach ($user in $Groups) {
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Group -Members $user.extensionAttribute1
  Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute1 -eq '$($user.extensionAttribute1)'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ansgar.

After trying your code, I realised that I had the ordering the wrong way round so below is how I managed to get it to work. I couldn't have done it though without your clear description for the misunderstanding I had.

```
$Groups = import-csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\GroupMembership.csv"

Foreach($user in $Groups){       
$Member = Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute1 -eq '$($user.ExtensionAttribute1)'"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Group -Members $Member
}
```

Thank you.